# Is it possible to put 2 command in one string in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have created simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
column=${1:-1}
awk '{colawk='$column'+1; print colawk}'
```

But when I run:

```
ls -la | ./Column.sh 4
```

I receive output:
 5
 5
 5
 5

But I have expected receive 5th column. Why this error?

Comment: To extract the value at a particular column in awk, you must use the dollar sign: `print $colawk` -- regular variables don't need the sigil, but the column's value does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this will do what you've attempted in your example:

```
#!/bin/sh
let "column=${1:-1} + 1"
awk "{print \$$column}"
```

However, I don't see why you're adding one to the column index? You'll then not be able to intuitively access the first column.

I'd to it this way instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
let "column=${1:-1}"
awk "{print \$$column}"
```

The argument to `./Column.sh` will be the column number you want, `0` will give you all columns, while a call without arguments will default the column index to `1`.

---

> I know bash. I would like make arithmetic with AWK

In that case, how about:

```
#!/bin/sh
column=${1:-1}
awk 'BEGIN{colawk='$column'+1} {print $colawk}'
```

Or, simply:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'BEGIN{colawk='${1:-1}'+1} {print $colawk}'
```

Two things I changed in your script:

1. put the arithmetic in a `BEGIN{}` block since it only needs to be done once and not repeated for every input line.
2. "`print $colawk`" instead of "`print colawk`" so we're printing the column indexed by `colawk` instead of its value.

Comment: I know bash. I would like make arithmetic with AWK

Comment: or even `awk -v "col=${1:-1}" '{print $(col+1)}'`

Comment: Thanks @glenn. That looks a lot clearer that what I proposed.